# Convert factor into specific time zone date

Tags: r, date, timezone

I am trying to convert a factor into date format for specific region.

My table looks like this

```
Period                   State     

2019-03-01T04:05:00+10:0    NSW 

2019-03-01T04:05:00+10:00    QLD
```

I am trying to convert the period into a dateformat for the specific region as time zone for NSW and QLD will be different.

Already tried the lubridate package:

```
as.Date(df_total$Period, format = "%YYYY-%mm-%DD")
```

Iam getting `NA` while what I exactly need is the correct time for New South Wales and Queensland. Not sure if it can pick up the `+10` and also change that to date at the same time.

Comment: try with `anytime` `anytime("2019-03-01T04:05:00+10:0")#
[1] "2019-03-01 04:05:00 EST"`

Comment: @akrun - except NSW is in daylight savings in March, while Qld is not. I think that's the complication of this query.